# Backbone: Referencing collections in the app level view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the Backbone app listed below. When its started, it creates a restaurants collection and view of local restaurants in the users area. The user can later change their search area and then update the entire collection by submitting a search form.

#### The Problem: How can I reference the collection in the `search` method if it isn't related to the view?

Currently, I'm setting the restaurant collection and view as properties of the `App` view itself so that it can be easily referenced from within the method, but this seems in appropriate because the view isn't solely related to that collection.

Is it better to reference the collection as I have or is it better to reference it as `App.collection`, as backbone does when you in create views realted to collections with `Backbone.View.extend({collection: mycollection})`?

App view:

```
 var App = new (Backbone.View.extend({
      
      ...
      
      events: {
        submit: "search",
      },
      start: function(){
        App.render();
        App.restaurants = new App.Collections.Restaurants();
        App.restaurantsView = new App.Views.Restaurants({collection: App.restaurants});
        App.restaurants.fetch({});
      },
      search: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var payload = $( App.targets.searchForm ).serializeObject();
        App.restaurants.fetch({data: payload, processData: true,});
      },

      ...
   
}):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are big questions: How to structure a Backbone application, how to define and maintain module boundaries, and how to decouple modules while allowing notifications where needed, like between search and restaurants?

Big-picture answer: Look at something like [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/). It's a framework built on top of Backbone, it makes it easy to follow a lot of best practices, and it does some heavy lifting for you. David Sulc has an excellent [book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) about Marionette that covers all of those topics & more. Highly recommended.

Immediate-problem answer: Directly referencing objects outside of a single module (like search) is a bad idea. It couples together concerns that should be kept separate. At a minimum, think of adding an application-level event bus: search can trigger a search event, and the restaurant code can listen for that event and act on its collection in response. You could use something like the [backbone.wreqr](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) library's `EventAggregator` class, which is tailor-made for this kind of thing. In a pinch, you could use an instance of `Backbone.Events` to roll your own:

```
App.vent = _.extend( {}, Backbone.Events );
```

Trigger an event from search code like so:

```
App.vent.trigger('search', payload);
```

And in your `start` function, register to listen for that event:

```
App.vent.on('search', function(payload) {
    App.restaurants.fetch({data: payload, processData: true,});
});
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  Thanks for taking  the time to be so detailed.